# Java. Getting synchronous data in inner callback

Tags: java, android, inner-classes

I want the array of bytes that the android camera returns. As i expect to get it synchronously I am doing the code below waiting the callback to complete... but coming from c++ I guess there's something I don't get correctly. In my function I want to return an array of bytes provided in the callback. I've tries several combinations until this one that still has a problem. In the sameple below jpegCallback.jpgData gives "can not find symbol (the field jpgData)". (I am doing this on Qt but I think the problem is strictly related to java (and me)). Thanks for any insight.

> ```
> public static byte[] CameraTakePicture(){
>
>     final CountDownLatch jpgWaiter = new CountDownLatch(1);
>
>     Camera.PictureCallback jpgCallback=new Camera.PictureCallback(){
>
>         public byte[] jpgData;
>
>         @Override
>         public void onPictureTaken(byte[] data,Camera cam){
>
>             jpgData=data;
>             jpgWaiter.countDown();
>         }
>     };
>
>     camera.takePicture(null,null,null,jpgCallback);
>     jpgWaiter.await();
>     byte[] jpgData=jpgCallback.jpgData.clone();
>     return jpgData;
> }
> ```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the Java perspective, your `jpgCallback` is of type `Camera.PictureCallback`, and the runtime has no knowledge of the presence of a public `jpgData` field in objects of type `Camera.PictureCallback`.

You would have to subclass `Camera.PictureCallback` to be able to access your public field.

Answer (score 1):

You are creating an anonymous inner class, which means it is an unnamed *subclass* of `PictureCallback`. Since the `PictureCallback` interface doesn't declare a `jpgData` field, you can't access it.

Also, generally speaking, it's not a good idea to shoehorn that sort of async call into a synchronous pattern. Why don't you return a `Future<byte[]>` instead?